# How to use 'datetimeZoneId' config in Spark Bigquery connector

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, spark-bigquery-connector

There is a 'datetimeZoneId' config in Spark Bigquery Connector. How this config works ? I did follow the explanation and documentation https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector, but couldn't understand completely.

A working example would really help to understand how this config works exactly.
Can someone please explain how to use 'datetimeZoneId' by giving a working example.